# User Interface design books/resources for programmers

Tags: user-interface

I'm going to make my monthly trip to the bookstore soon and I'm kind of interested in learning some user interface and/or design stuff - mostly web related, what are some good books I should look at? One that I've seen come up frequently in the past is [Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758), which looks promising.

I'm aware of the fact that programmers often don't make great designers, and as such this is more of a potential hobby thing than a move to be a professional designer.

I'm also looking for any good web resources on this topic. I subscribed to Jakob Nielsen's [Alertbox newsletter](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/), for instance, although it seems to come only once a month or so.

Thanks!

Somewhat related questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863/what-are-the-best-resources-for-designing-user-interfaces
[User Interface Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973/user-interface-design)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good books/resources for User Interface design ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868297/good-books-resources-for-user-interface-design)

Comment: Serious question: can a question asked in October 2008 be considered a duplicate of a question asked in May 2009?

Answer (score 16):

[Don't Make Me Think](http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html) is the one!

Also check out [Steve Krug's website](http://www.sensible.com/) for tips and sample forms for usability testing.

Comment: Thanks.  I had the pleasure of hearing him speak at Business of Software 2008 and it's even better in person.  :-)

Answer (score 10):

[The design of everyday things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465067107) ? An "old" classic, but useful if you plan anything that requires human interaction.

Answer (score 8):

Joel Spolsky's [User Interface Design for Programmers](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html) is at least entertaining, and a recommended read.

Answer (score 7):

Tufte, Visual Display of Quantitative Information http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/

Don Norman, Design of Everyday Things http://www.jnd.org/

Answer (score 5):

Although completely independent of web and programming, [The Design of Everyday Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465067107) by Donald Norman taught me a lot!

For a less in-depth, more cook-book approach (if you don't want to think), try Robin Williams' [The Non-Designer's Design Book: Design and Typographic Principles for the Visual Novice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1566091594).

Presonally I much prefer The Design of Everyday Things.

Answer (score 4):

Also take a look at Alan Cooper's *About Face*.

Answer (score 2):

The [Apple Human Interface Guidlines](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/chapter_1_section_1.html) are great!

Comment: Thanks, do you think these are useful from a general design perspective as well? e.g. they transcend developing interfaces on the Mac/Iphone/whatever

Comment: Many of these things can be applied to non-MacOS stuff. For more specific things there are special guides like "iPhone Human Interface Guidelines", or the Gnome HIG (http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/).

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly related to GUI design or programming, but The Psychology of Everyday Things is a good book to read.

It is a general look at how things are designed and how they fail.  The concepts in this book, although not directly applicable to GUI's, do apply.  In fact you could say they apply to all instances of user centered design.

[http://www.amazon.com/Psychology-Everyday-Things-Donald-Norman/dp/0465067093](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465067093)

Comment: Is this in fact the same book as The Design of Everyday Things, just with a new name?

Comment: Psychology of Everyday Things (POET) was the original name of the book. It was changed to Design of Everyday Things. Did they go back to the original name?

Comment: It was changed from Psychology to Design to stop it being filed in the  psychology section of libraries. The Design of Everyday Things is it's current name.

Answer (score 1):

**AboutFace.3.0**
The Essentials of Interaction Design would be good Idea to read

Answer (score 0):

"Don't Make Me Think" is great.  After sitting in on several usability studies I can safely say that several of his biggest points are the kinds of things drilled in your head over and over.

Joel Spolsky's book on user interfaces is also decent.

[http://www.amazon.com/User-Interface-Design-Programmers-Spolsky/dp/1893115941](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1893115941)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the great hints given so far, also see the [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](https://web.archive.org/web/20151126214052/http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/1/9/e191fd8c-bce8-4dba-a9d5-2d4e3f3ec1d3/ux%20guide.pdf), as described in this interesting [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kirillosenkov/windows-user-interface-guidelines) by Kirill Osenkov.