# Looking for some examples of GUI apps with great design

Tags: user-interface

I will start developing my next desktop application in about a month. In the past I have delivered functional software that hasn't wowed anyone, including myself, in the usability or aesthetics department.

Does anybody know of any resources or guides or even books that could showcase examples of good design in desktop software?

There seems to be a lot of resources for web apps, but such resources for desktop applications are rather slim.

Comment: This isn't worthy of an "answer", but I thought I'd mention: many of the interfaces I've really enjoyed have been minimalistic -- there's almost nothing for me to see. Like QuickSilver for OS X.

Answer (score 5):

I enjoyed [these dot net rocks tv videos by Mark Miller on The Science of a Great User Experience](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=112) really got me thinking about good ui:

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=112

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=123

Answer (score 2):

Where you can really make a difference with GUI design is if you are addressing a difficult to understand concept in a GUI.

When you are doing that, creativity is critical.  When dealing with complex hardware configurations (something I had to do a lot, but probably doesn't apply to you), I've had good luck going to tech manuals and tech support people and trying to completely understand the problem.  Then I took the methods they used to show me (diagrams from the manuals, whiteboard drawings, etc) and tried to code them into a GUI.

Had a couple massive successes with this.

Iteration is also critical.  Prototype something quickly then beg everyone you see to try it.  Ask them to solve a problem, then watch where they go first and watch what they have problems with.

Address every problem and stumbling block.

Don't be afraid to throw it all away and start over, it was only prototype code.

Separate your GUI from your implementation so that you can swap out the GUI if you find a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concentrate on just one feature, have a look at ITunes' search box which filters as you type. Other software may have had this before, but this was I think the first place I encountered it.

The difference between this and classic search was an eye opener for me in terms of readability.

Auto-complete which you see in so many places is another one. I'd recommend IntelliJ IDEA for the way it took auto-completion which emacs, Visual studio etc had for ages and added autocompletion for variable names and method names in a manner which almost seemed psychic the first time you encountered it.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Thirteen23 Experiences](http://www.thirteen23.com/experiences/)

Comment: I hope their webpage design isn't indicative of their applications.  I'm at 1680x1050 resolution and had to scroll down to get to the menu at the bottom due to the overly huge graphics at the top.

Answer (score 1):

To make things usable, you need to make sure that you follow existing conventions for your target platform and application type.

For example, if you're developing a Windows App you'd better make sure that control-c copies, control-v pastes, control-s saves, etc.  The File menu better be the leftmost item in the menu bar, and the Help menu better by the rightmost item.

If you don't follow existing conventions, users are going to get annoyed with your application very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Google for HIG.  Human Interface Guidelines typically include lots of research into best-practice in user interfaces, and explain in great detail how to design each aspect of a program.  Also, have a google for "user-interface hall of shame" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556478/top-tips-for-designing-guis) I mentioned [GUI bloopers](http://www.gui-bloopers.com/). Part of great design is knowing what makes bad design and why. It is actually a great book, although I don't know how much of it is available on the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can check case studys  on websites of GUI companys. I fund few at [www.puzzlehead.com](http://www.puzzlehead.com)

Check there and also other sites.