# Help me understand JS + CSS + HTML = Cool UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, usability

I have been working on the UI since year or two. Many times i have satisfied myself with the JQuery, YUI and Prototype. But gradually i have been feeling the need to understand how these small things are assembled together.

I am able to find basics of CSS, JS and HTML with good books and blogs. But main mysteries i think lies in the UI component as a whole which is finished product of smart JS, CSS and HTML markup tricks.

Say for example a simple slick sliding div appearing and disparaging on the UI. Classic feature reach tables which are sortable, deletion operation slowly eating the row and stuff.

I would like to get into the basics of how these small small things and patters are implemented and integrated to form whole picture. Can some one guide me into this please.

Comment: Great question, and one I would have asked myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Designing Interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/) an excellent book on user interaction.

[UI-patterns.com](http://ui-patterns.com/) has a vast wealth of examples.

This "[15 Design Patterns](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/11/03/15-ui-design-patterns-web-designers-should-keep-handy/)" is a good round up of standard patterns.

And finally here's a "[40 helpful resources](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/)" post.

You'll have to use your experience to flesh out these basic designs, but they're a good example of what you should work towards.

Answer (score 0):

The Smashing book is also good.

https://shop.smashingmagazine.com/

Answer (score 0):

Very good question but basically it comes to the same result as 
questions like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158769/best-books-to-learn-about-design
[User Interface design books/resources for programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221966/user-interface-design-books-resources-for-programmers)

@DVK summs it pretty much up in his answer to find more ressources on the specific topic you want to know more about

[Good Web Designing Books for Programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672024/good-web-designing-books-for-programmers)